# D3.js removing element doesn't work as expected

Tags: d3.js

I am building a visualization of a popular brain teaser. So far there are 9 balls on SVG with drag behavior, collision detection and forceY.

I am trying to remove them by dragging. Which kinda works... But not the way it is supposed.

One of balls is yellow. When it is dragged, it should get removed. This works, but the bug is that another ball gets rendered yellow.

Here is the function that deals with the functionality and below is fiddle.

```
function dragended(d, i) {
    balls.splice(i, 1);

    var update = svgBalls.data(balls)
    update.exit().remove()

    simulation.alphaTarget(0.1);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Anuar/21738t3g/

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a solution in the narrow sense of the term, but simply an **explanation** of your problem.

If we slightly change your data array...

```
var balls = [{id:0, color:false},{id:1, color:false},{id:2, color:false},
    {id:3, color:false}, {id:4, color:false}, {id:5, color:false}, 
    {id:6, color:false}, {id:7, color:false},{id:8, color:false}];
```

... in such a way that we can set a key function...

```
svgBalls.data(balls, d => d.id)
```

... you're gonna see that this line:

```
balls.splice(i, 1);
```

Is not correctly removing the dragged element. If you change for this:

```
balls = balls.filter(d => d.id != i);
```

It will work.

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/27sykjxd/

Comment: Thank you, man! It works perfectly! How does filter work differently from splice? Do you have online courses?

Comment: Thanks. No, I don't have one, but I'm an author (evolutionary biology, nothing related to programming) and I really want to write about D3 someday. Back to your question: `splice` is very complicated: for start, it mutates the array that calls it.